# How to find a button in selenium?(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to find this button in selenium:

```
<input class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Send me the code" data-type="save">
```

I tried this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Send me the code']").click()
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: There are many reasons it could not be working if its not found potentially the button could be placed within an iframe which means you need to switch to that frame first before searching for the button

Comment: @cruisepandey no error but it is not clicking the button

Comment: @AtomStore : Please see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//input[@value='Send me the code']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Send me the code']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Send me the code']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Send me the code']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Send me the code']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons why a simple code line like `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Send me the code']").click()` may not work properly.
The most likely reason could be missing a wait / delay.  You should wait until the element is fully loaded before trying accessing it. Instead using `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Send me the code']").click()` Please try something like this:

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Send me the code']"))).click()
```

To use this you will need the following imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And to initialize `wait` object

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

Also it is possible the locator is not unique.
Also the element can be located inside iframe etc.